# How to open zip raster tif file with spatial information in rasterio python

Tags: zip, raster, rasterio

I am trying to import zip raster tif file which include spatial information such as ovr. ,tfw. and aux.xml. file extensions. However, I couldn't find any code of opening raster zip file.

As follows, tif file is composed of four small files to have right projection and coordinates. They are again compressed in one zip file. Therefore, my purpose is to open the following four files all together to get an image in rasterio with the right "Transform/ Affine" information.

[Screenshot of the small four files of a raster tif file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sngfc.png)

Otherwise, when I open the tif file in the rasterio, the Transform information is out of the world as follow. `Affine(1.9800000000000022, -0.0, 752184.0447924964, -0.0, -1.9800000000000022, 1850957.477092044)`
Therefore, when I export the tif file in rasterio, the location is wrong.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community Thank you so much for your kind comment. I have edited the question accordingly. Hope it explain better. Simply my purpose is to open a tif file with the right transform/ Affirm information so that when I export it, the result has a right location in real world.